# Can't install apk file on samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1). "Package A.B.C has mismatched uid" and "Can't byte swap: bad dex version"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have Unity project and it works fine for all devices except samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1).

Here is the log:

```
 01-29 16:20:50.550: D/installd(228): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/ABC.apk' ---
01-29 16:20:50.550: E/PackageManager(296): Package A.B.C has mismatched uid: 10106 on disk, 10107 in settings
01-29 16:20:50.550: I/PackageManager(296): Linking native library dir for /data/app/ABC.apk
01-29 16:20:50.570: E/dalvikvm(1132): ERROR: Can't byte swap: bad dex version (0x30 33 36 00)
01-29 16:20:50.570: E/dalvikvm(1132): ERROR: Byte swap + verify failed
01-29 16:20:50.890: E/dalvikvm(1132): Optimization failed
01-29 16:20:50.890: W/installd(228): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/ABC.apk' --- status=0xff00, process failed
01-29 16:20:50.890: E/installd(228): dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@ABC.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280
01-29 16:20:50.900: W/PackageManager(296): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/ABC.apk
01-29 16:20:50.980: D/dalvikvm(296): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1360K, 48% free 16024K/30791K, paused 10ms+5ms
01-29 16:20:50.990: D/AndroidRuntime(1123): Shutting down VM
```

May be anybody got the same errors.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.